# NSOperationQueue blocking tableview refresh

Tags: uitableview, io, nsmanagedobject, nsoperationqueue, reloaddata

I have been using NSOperationQueue to download some data from server on background.
i have multiple data to be downloaded .So multiple operation is added to queue for each data download
there UITableview which i need to refresh once single data is received.
I have used KVO approache to track "isFinished" key for each operation finish.
But when i refresh tableview all delgates for tableview is called but table isnt refreshed.
i also see from my console logs that even when tableview isnt refreshed completely,i see logs from worker thread (is used for background download of data).
So thats why my table isnt refresh completely?
What could be work around for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be nice to see some code, but one of the possible reasons could be that you are running reloadData from a background queue.

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
```

Comment: there where many operation added to queue so operation where getting finish very quick & so tableview is getting reload lots of times & one call is overlapped by another.I did a workaround by making tableview reload once for batch of say when 100 operation are completed.Then tableview seems refresh properly